# Yii: How to upload with fetch()?

Tags: file-upload, yii, yii2, fetch

I have a model and controller for a view with Dropzone.js which works fine. But in another view, which is just a form that uses fetch(), I get an Bad Request from Yii. My two questions: A) Is there a way to get more detailed errors what’s wrong with my request. B) Why is fetch() not working? It should, right ...?

Here is the form:

```html
<form action="/files/upload" onsubmit="filesSave(event, this)">
    <input type="hidden" name="<?= Yii::$app->request->csrfParam ?>" value="<?= Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken() ?>">
                    
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Here is the fetch():

```js
function filesSave(event, form) {
    event.preventDefault();

    fetch(form.action, {
        method: 'post',
        body: new FormData(form),
        headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
    }).then(response => response.text()).then(response => {
        
    });
}
```

**Update:** I solved it by removing the headers in fetch() and put it in the form tag.

Comment: Did you see csrf in `formData(form)`?

Comment: whats in the `form` ? can you add `console.log(form)` as the first line in the function and see what it shows in the console

Comment: Thanks for responsing, I edited my post with a solution. Weird that it’s working only this way. Maybe someone can explain?